# Flutter Opening Listview items on a speacial page

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am making a food order application where I will add many foods to the the boxes below. I tried creating pages but it makes about 60 pages and this is too much for it. Can I open all listview boxes in one page? I will get the data from the mysql api. If you have any suggestion please let me know thanks.

[image]

```
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Menu"),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: Card(
                shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: new Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg",
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print("hello");
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: Card(
                shape: border,
                child: Text("box2"),
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: Card(
                shape: border,
                child: Text("box3"),
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: Card(
                shape: border,
                child: Text("box4"),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: Card(
                shape: border,
                child: Text("box4"),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: padding,
              child: Card(
                shape: border,
                child: Text("box4"),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
           ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a class like `FoodItem`. (hold image path, name and etc property in it)
2. Create `List<FoodItem>`
3. Use map operator to convert `List<FoodItem>` to UI.
4. Alternative of this is approach is use [Hero animation](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-hero-widgets-in-flutter-d34f441eb026) to open new page on item click.

Following is the code for your reference.

```
class FoodItem {
  // add other properties like title name or etc in this class.
  final String imageAssetPath;

  final String name;

  FoodItem(this.name, this.imageAssetPath);
}

List<FoodItem> _foodItems = <FoodItem>[
  FoodItem("Item 1", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 2", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 3", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 4", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 5", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 6", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 7", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 8", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 9", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
  FoodItem("Item 10", "android/assets/images/lunch.jpeg"),
];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final padding = EdgeInsets.all(8.0);
    final border = BeveledRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'title',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Menu"),
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: _foodItems.map((FoodItem item) {
              return Padding(
                padding: padding,
                child: Card(
                  shape: border,
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: new Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            item.imageAssetPath,
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  FoodItemWidget(item: item)));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(growable: false)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FoodItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final FoodItem item;

  const FoodItemWidget({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(
        child: Text(item.name),
      ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: i meant when i clicked boxes it should open a page different page for each boxes

Comment: I have updated the code please check, you can set properties in FoodItem class and whichever instance you pass to the FoodItemWidget, the UI will be inflated accordingly.